# Using Like and Where statement form table to search for something from only specific columns

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to search for a specific matches in columns using multiple Like statements from a table but that search should be from specific columns.

Trying to execute this MySQL statement for PHP

```
SELECT count(*) FROM morefiles where file like '%.doc%' or file like '%.pdf%' or file like '%.txt%' AND assignto=882 


TABLE
-------
id | ProductId | file
0       882      myfile.pdf
1       831      thisfile.docx
2       232      files.mp3
3       882      otherfile.pdf
4       882      textfile.doc
```

The result I'm getting

```
TABLE
-------
id | ProductId | file
0       882      myfile.pdf
1       831      thisfile.docx
3       882      otherfile.pdf
4       882      textfile.doc
```

Result I expect

```
TABLE
-------
id | ProductId | file
0       882      myfile.pdf
3       882      otherfile.pdf
4       882      textfile.doc
```

Means I want to search to show only ProductID of 882, not others

Comment: AND binds stronger than OR. Right now, you are saying you want `.txt` files that are assigned to 882 - or just any files that end with `.doc` or `.pdf`. You need to put your OR-joined partial conditions into a set of grouping braces here.

Comment: @misorude I don't get it how?

Comment: *sigh* `where ( file like '%.doc%' or file like '%.pdf%' or file like '%.txt%' ) AND assignto=882`

Comment: Oh my bad that's great now I got what you meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Braces should fix your problem.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM morefiles 
where assignto=882
and (file like '%.doc%' or file like '%.pdf%' or file like '%.txt%');
```

Comment: Yup that's what all I needed thanks for your contribution

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM morefiles 
WHERE file LIKE '%.doc' 
    OR file LIKE '%.pdf%' 
    OR file like '%.txt%' 
    AND assignto=882;
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would use the function [`substring_index()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to avoid all these `OR`s (which otherwise need to be enclosed in parentheses since they have lower precedence than `AND`):

```
select * from tablename
where productid = '882'
and substring_index(file, '.', -1) in ('doc', 'pdf', 'txt')
```

`substring_index()` with `-1` as the last argument returns the part of the string after the last dot.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tTdWjW1hoHPr5qK7RokVBH/1).
Results:

```
| id  | ProductId | file          |
| --- | --------- | ------------- |
| 0   | 882       | myfile.pdf    |
| 3   | 882       | otherfile.pdf |
| 4   | 882       | textfile.doc  |
```

If you need only to count the number of files under these conditions:

```
select sum(
    productid = '882'
    and 
    substring_index(file, '.', -1) in ('doc', 'pdf', 'txt')
  ) as counter
from tablename
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tTdWjW1hoHPr5qK7RokVBH/3).
Results:

```
| counter |
| ------- |
| 3       |
```